# Watson Conversation Doesn't Recognize New Entities

Tags: watson-conversation

When adding training examples to an intent, it seems the intents don't have the capability to match against untrained entities.

Given the following intent training:

[image]

If I test out my intent, I match the intent, but I want to detect the entity even if it's not trained in the intent training set. Here are my results for an untrained entity.

[image]

Notice the example test case is identical to the first training user example. The only difference is 'grapes'. Can Watson conversation still provide the unmatched entity 'grapes' so my dialog can continue without re-prompting?

Is there a way to provide a variable in the user example training to match strings?

Why am I asking for this? ***The user can virtually ask for anything, so there isn't a finite set of entities.***

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna use just Conversation service, you need to train the Intent #WhatPrices using examples for asking prices and create entities with the correspondent values for Watson Conversation recognize inside the Conversation.

But, if you wanna to detect this words even if it's not trained in the intent training set, you can use AlchemyLanguage API's to detect the keyword in each phrase typed or use NLU to get the keywords, see the [Demo](https://alchemy-language-demo.mybluemix.net/) example.

For example:

When I typed on [NLU demo](https://natural-language-understanding-demo.mybluemix.net/):

- "What is the price for two banana?"

They recognize the keyword: `bread` and `price`. And you can use the `output` (`JSON`) and do something in your application, all depends on your business role.

- See [this](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/alchemylanguage/customizing.html#example-request) example using Alchemy Language.
- See the Official [Documentation](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/alchemylanguage/index.html#about-alchemylanguage) for use AlchemyLanguage and the [API Reference](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/alchemy-language/api/v1/#introduction).
- See the Official [Documentation](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/natural-language-understanding/) for use Natural Language Understand and the [API Reference](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/natural-language-understanding/api/v1/).

Obs.: Maybe this information can help you. Probably have others forms but one IBM professional will answer if have.